# HTML - Drop Down Value based on another Drop Down Value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When i Select the Value First Year in the first drop down, i need the values Sem1 and Sem2 to be shown in the second drop-down, likewise when i select Second Year in the first drop down i need the values Sem3 and Sem4 to appear in the second drop down and so on!!! Please Help, the codes are listed below:

Code for the First Drop Down:

```
<select name="class"  class="form-control">
                      <option value="none">Select Year</option>
                      <option value="First_Year">First Year</option>
                      <option value="Second_Year">Second Year</option>
                      <option value="Third_Year">Third Year</option>
                      <option value="Fourth_Year">Fourth Year</option>
</select>
```

Code for the Second Drop Down:

```
<select name="semester"  class="form-control">
                      <option value="none">Select Semester</option>
                      <option value="Sem-1">Semester 1</option>
                      <option value="Sem-2">Semester 2</option>
                      <option value="Sem-3">Semester 3</option>
                      <option value="Sem-4">Semester 4</option>
                      <option value="Sem-5">Semester 5</option>
                      <option value="Sem-6">Semester 6</option>
                      <option value="Sem-7">Semester 7</option>
                      <option value="Sem-8">Semester 8</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the solution I have added some selectors. Try the following way:

```js
$('#year').change(function(){
  $('#semester option').show();
  var year = $(this).val();
  if(year == 'First_Year'){
    $('#semester option:not(".year1")').hide();
  }
  else if(year == 'Second_Year'){
    $('#semester option:not(".year2")').hide();
  }
  else if(year == 'Third_Year'){
    $('#semester option:not(".year3")').hide();
  }
  else if(year == 'Fourth_Year'){
    $('#semester option:not(".year4")').hide();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="class" id="year"  class="form-control">
  <option value="none">Select Year</option>
  <option value="First_Year">First Year</option>
  <option value="Second_Year">Second Year</option>
  <option value="Third_Year">Third Year</option>
  <option value="Fourth_Year">Fourth Year</option>
</select>

<select name="semester" id="semester" class="form-control">
  <option value="none">Select Semester</option>
  <option class="year1" value="Sem-1">Semester 1</option>
  <option class="year1" value="Sem-2">Semester 2</option>
  <option class="year2" value="Sem-3">Semester 3</option>
  <option class="year2" value="Sem-4">Semester 4</option>
  <option class="year3" value="Sem-5">Semester 5</option>
  <option class="year3" value="Sem-6">Semester 6</option>
  <option class="year4" value="Sem-7">Semester 7</option>
  <option class="year4" value="Sem-8">Semester 8</option>
</select>
```